# Creating an HTML Table, with merged columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to created a Table with the following structure, but I don't know how to do it.

### |----------Deduction---------------------|----------------------Incentive------------|

### |Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3|

DATROW 1 | DATROW 2 | DATROW 3| DATROW 1 | DATROW 2 | DATROW 3|
DATROW 1 | DATROW 2 | DATROW 3| DATROW 1 | DATROW 2 | DATROW 3|
DATROW 1 | DATROW 2 | DATROW 3| DATROW 1 | DATROW 2 | DATROW 3|

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show us your code? and are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge two or more table cells together by using the colspan attribute in a `<td>` HTML tag (table data). For example, in the below code is a table with three rows and three columns. If we wanted to combine the first two cells into one cell, we could use the `colspan="2"` attribute in the first `<td>` tag. The number represents how many cells you want to use for the `<td>` tag.

Refer this link for example
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001655.htm

Answer (score 3):

USE `colspan` to do this. created a snippet it may you help to understand.

```html
<table border='1'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Deduction</th>
            <th colspan="3">Incentive</th>
        </tr>
   
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
      
         </thead>
    <tbody>
      
      
        <tr>
            <td>DATROW 1</td>
            <td>DATROW 2</td>
            <td>DATROW 3</td>
            <td>DATROW 1</td>
            <td>DATROW 2</td>
            <td>DATROW 3</td>
        </tr>
      
        <tr>
            <td>DATROW 1</td>
            <td>DATROW 2</td>
            <td>DATROW 3</td>
            <td>DATROW 1</td>
            <td>DATROW 2</td>
            <td>DATROW 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `colspan` HTML attribute, you may merge columns.

So, you may do it like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Deduction</th>
            <th colspan="3">Incentive</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>DATROW 1</td>
            <td>DATROW 2</td>
            <td>DATROW 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```